# Sharepoint Online & Azure Tokens

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to authorise login for a c# app that uses CSOM to query Sharepoint lists and pnp.core to get the client context.

I have an app registration with a client secret. The registration has the permissions Allsites.read & Allsites.write

```
   string siteUrl ="mysite";
   string clientId = "my app client id";
   string tenantId = "my tenant id";
   string clientSecret = "*******";

    using var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager()
                             .GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret); 
      clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
      Console.WriteLine(clientContext.Web.Title);
```

The above code seems to read the key OK (if I change the secret it fails with a key invalid error) but when I try and access the title property of the web I get a 403 Forbidden error.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong here, so any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllSites.Read` and `AllSites.Write` permissions are tied with the signed-in user but you connect as a daemon without a signed-in user.

In that case you need to add application permissions `Sites.ReadWrite.All` in Azure AD.

[image]

Comment: ahh, I thought I'd done that but you are correct, I'd done it under the user account not the delegated permissions section.

I also had to grant admin consent after adding those permissions.

I'm still getting the same error, but hoping it is a propagation issue now

Comment: Issue persists, so I think I'm missing something else ?

Comment: @SeanConnolly Did you follow this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs or another one?

Comment: Different one, that got me to add the token directly in Azure AD underneath App registrations.

Having now done it using the two Sharepoint admin urls, it now works, but the app shows up underneath enterprise app registrations and the permissions I granted via xml on the second admin page are not there.

It all works now, but it doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense to me how